# C++: Any way to access a string from another function?

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>

void f() {
  printf("target_string");
}

int main(){
  //any way to access target_string?
}
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

---

I know if I define the string as a global variable, I can achieve that easily.

But, actually, I'm trying to explore the hidden feature of C++ and I just wonder that is possible or not...

Comment: target_string is not an object. Define it outside `f() `

Comment: Why do you need this? But usual way is using variables.

Comment: Maybe but for a very specific compiler/version. Duplicated strings may be merged. However you will play with UB and it may work (or not) by case also according to performed optimizations (and a small unrelated code change may break it...). What do you exactly mean with "access"?

Comment: since this is "hacking" and not formal programming, the short answer is yes you can, you'd need some tries , you'll most likely crash your system many times, but it still possible, throw a pointer to a memory address before the string, and advance till you find it

Comment: No... you can't access that.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti definition of access: print `targer_string` to stdout without a literal `targer_string` or something like that.

Comment: Which toolchain are you using? With GNU (if I'm not wrong...) you can have a script in _Linker Command Language_ to _drive_ `ld`. In that case (not sure about details, honestly I never did it) you know where `"target_string"` is located (and for read-only tasks it should be safe to access it because it has static storage duration). If you can't do that then it's hard because it may be anywhere (but possibly in a data section or a read-only data section, if available)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes, it's G++. Could please explain the `have a script to drive ld`?

Comment: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html (but it's a pretty weak kind of hacking if you need to be able to control how the executable is linked to put a string literal at a known address ... if you control the link process you can do far more damage!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disassemble your little program and have a look at where your string is stored. If your string is stored let's say five bytes after or before some function or command then use this information to locate where your string will be. Use a pointer to point at your string, and access it.

Example:

```
0xff7722: mov eax, 7 #beginn of your function 
...
0xff7727: #your string

0xff7727 - 0xff7722 = 5;

void* pointer = &f;
f+=5;
```

f points to your string.

Your pointer may point to a wrong location if your compiler decides to put your pointer in between your string and your function.

Comment: It's incredibly _fragile_. Any minor - unrelated - change may break this assumption. It's even architecture dependent if you can do pointer arithmetic between code segment and (read-only)data segment